# Assembly Code in QTSpim is Not Properly Taking User Input

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am working on a code for my assembly language class that takes user input and stores it in memory and then prints it out again for the user.  I don't know what the problem is but ever time I invoke the system call code to read the users input it always skips the first 2 letters.  The following is my code.

```
.data

myname: .asciiz "Please Type Your Name:"
ram1:   .word 4
ram2:   .word 4
blank:  .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main

main:

    li $v0, 4        #loads the system call code to print a string
    la $a0, myname
    syscall

    la $a0, ram1
    li $a1, 20
    li $v0, 8        #this is the opcode that reads a user input in the console
    syscall

    li   $v0, 4      #loads the call code to print a string
    la   $a0, blank
    andi $a1, $a1, 0
    syscall
    syscall
    syscall

    la $a0, myname
    syscall
    la $a0, ram1
    syscall
```

I understand that the system call code 8 requires 2 arguments to function properly which I added.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Why did you only reserve one word (four bytes) for you buffer? Many people have longer names than that. And why are there three `syscall` instructions in a row at one point in your program?

Comment: I reserved 8 bytes for my buffer that is why there is ram 1 and ram 2.  The three syscall instructions are to print spaces in between the user input and the final output.  It's part of the instructions for this assignment.